# selecting a single value from the derived list from mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

how can i get to choose a single value and click it which i have extracted from my database
i'm using this code

```
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ***");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
    echo '<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
       echo '<tr><td><a href="***" target="condition">'.$row['name'].'</a></td></tr>';
        }

     }
```

now the problem is when i click it it is selecting the entire list which i've retrieved from db
can i select only one item from the derived list and  utilize that value to display the results from the item in the selected row

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

You can LIMIT your query to Y results starting from the Xst result.

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE LIMIT X,Y;
```

Comment: i'm asking how can i utilize php inside java script so when i click on it the value should  be stored in a variable and it should be passed and used in my sqlquery so that i can extract some other value in the same row

Answer (score 0):

You have shown us your server side PHP code. You've not shown us what .js (browser side) scripting you have done, in order to detect the click event. Are you asking for someone to write the entire javascript portion? Hope not.

This will help you get started.... add dynamically assigned div id's to your rows, then goolgle javascript click events.

Comment: i just need the value i clicked that's it

Comment: Clicking is detected from event driven browser side js. Not from within server side PHP. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: i'm asking how can i utilize php inside java script so when i click on it the value should be stored in a variable and it should be passed and used in my sqlquery so that i can extract some other value in the same row

Comment: can u verify this js      <script type="text/javascript">
function clicked() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<?php echo $value ?>";
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM head");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     echo '<p id="demo" target="condition">'.$row['possible_condition'].'</p>';

    } ?>
}

</script>